# Verilog mode to navigate from begin to end

Tags: code-folding, verilog

I am using verilog mode for Emacs. I am trying to find which `begin` is paired with which `end`.  Is there any way to do this in Emacs?

Answer (score 1):

Use `M-x verilog-begin-of-defun` and `M-x verilog-end-of-defun`

which you can bind to a key in your init file like:

```
(eval-after-load 'verilog-mode 
  '(define-key verilog-mode-map (kbd "C-{") 'verilog-beg-of-defun))
```

and:

```
(eval-after-load 'verilog-mode 
  '(define-key verilog-mode-map (kbd "C-}") 'verilog-end-of-defun))
```

that will bind `C-{` and `C-}` to beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an evil user you can use [evil-matchit](https://github.com/redguardtoo/evil-matchit/blob/master/README.org) to jump between verilog tags.

Answer (score 0):

Standard motions by defuns seem to work in this mode just fine. You can simply use <kbd>C-M-a</kbd> and <kbd>C-M-e</kbd> to move to beginnings and ends respectively.